# Is there a design pattern for that : send a blank form and receive it back compeleted

Tags: rest, design-patterns, microservices

Is there a design pattern for that ?
A rest microservice receives a JSon data structure, with no value (but maybe an id) and returns back the same data with blanks filed? Example :

Input :

```
{
    id: 1546,
    name: ,
    height: ,
    color:
}
```

Output :

```
{
    id: 1546,
    name: "Bob",
    height: 40,
    color: "yellow"
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, in the asynchronous world it's called the [Document Message pattern](http://www.enterpriseintegrationpatterns.com/patterns/messaging/DocumentMessage.html). This can be easily adapted to synchronous communication.

In your case the document is passed from one service to another and then sent back completed. More details [here](http://www.informit.com/articles/article.aspx?p=1398616&seqNum=2).